# How to close a luks container that has sub partitions

Tags: linux, luks

For example this creates 1 partition on /dev/sda, as /dev/sda1, which is turned into a LUKS container, which is further partitioned into 2 sub partitions:

```
sgdisk -Z /dev/sda
sgdisk -n 1:0:0 -t 1:8300 -c 1:"Test Partition" /dev/sda

cryptsetup -v --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --key-size 512 --hash sha512 --iter-time 1000 --use-urandom luksFormat /dev/sda1
cryptsetup luksOpen --allow-discards "test_encrypted"

sgdisk -Z /dev/mapper/test_encrypted
sgdisk -n 1:0:+6GB -t 1:8300 -c 1:"sub_test_1" /dev/mapper/test_encrypted
sgdisk -n 2:0:0 -t 2:8300 -c 2:"sub_test_2" /dev/mapper/test_encrypted

partprobe -s /dev/mapper/test_encrypted

lsblk

cryptsetup luksClose test_encrypted
```

Trying to do so, gives back: `device-mapper: remove ioctl on test_encrypted failed: Device or resource busy`, then `Device test_encrypted is still in use`.

The sub partitioning works, but one cannot close it anymore once partprobe has reported to the kernel about the sub partitions.

Comment: If I were using LVM, one could use `vgchange -an /dev/vgCloseMe` the close. But I'm not using LVM.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://unix.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kpartx` allows deletion of partition mappings with the `-d` argument. I recommend using it instead if `partprobe` is unable to support this.

Comment: I have `partx` but not `kpartx`, tried using the `-d` argument but nothing changed.

Comment: partx is not kpartx.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. What's the difference between the 2?

Comment: partx is a tool for creating and deleting partitions. kpartx is part of dm-multipath.